# xstream primitive deserialization doesn't work?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I'm using XStream serializer to serialize a primitive and faced problem with deserializing it. Here is the problem description:

Say, I have:

```
int i = 80;
```

I serialize it as following:

```
serializer.toXML(i, new FileOutputStream("me.xml"));
```

and get the this xml:

```
<int>80</int>
```

But when I'm trying to deserealize:

```
i = (int) serializer.fromXML("me.xml");
```

I get the exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.FastStack.pop(FastStack.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
    at Utilities.Parser.serializeTimeIntervalDuration(Parser.java:371)
    at Utilities.Parser.parseData(Parser.java:152)
    at CoreLayer.Main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

Could anybody point me on my mistakes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `fromXML()` expects the XML, not a filename. You should read your XML in from the file prior to parsing it.

Note that [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html) has multiple implementations of fromXML(), so you can provide strings, URLs, readers etc.

At the moment XStream is trying to make sense of the string "me.xml".

Comment: Brian, thank you very much, that saved a lot of my time. I really appreciate it!